# Function overloading for char, signed char or unsigned char parameter type in terms of compiling template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

This is an open discussion about different ways to enable function overloading for parameters of only `char`, `signed char` or `unsigned char` type with the help of type traits in terms of C++11 template compiling.

Though satisfactory, a compound logic of `std::enable_if` and `std::is_same` type assertion (see PS) is not smart in that all matching types, particularly `char` in spite of signedness, are used in enumeration. Therefore I'm hoping someone can specify some other clause or compound logic that might facilitate type assertions better (maybe `std::is_integral`, `std::is_arithmetic` or `std::is_signed`?).

PS:

```
template <typename type>
void foo(std::enable_if<std::is_same<type, char>::value||std::is_same<type, signed char>::value||std::is_same<type, unsigned char>::value, type> x)
{
}
```

Comment: `char` is going to be exactly equivalent to either `signed char` or `unsigned char` so you really only have two choices.

Comment: @MarkRansom: These are three distinct types, therefore overloading will be required for all three ones.

Comment: I don't really get what you are asking. You say you want to enable the function for types x,y,z; so you have to specify those types you want to enable them for somehow...

Comment: @PlasmaHH, I didn't think that was the case. Do you have a reference?

Comment: Exactly, the three are distinctive.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I currently dont have the standards with me, but just try it out in your compiler, have a function that is overloaded for signed and unsigned char, and call it with a char argument. It will be ambiguous.

Comment: @MarkRansom : §3.9.1/1: "*Characters can be explicitly declared `unsigned` or `signed`. Plain `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are three distinct types.*" Plain `char` may _behave_ exactly equivalent to either `signed char` or `unsigned char`, but it's still a different type.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Simply, is there an assertion on type trait for char (including signed and unsigned) defined in <type_traits> the same as std::is_arithmetic?

Comment: @PlasmaHH, thanks for taking the time to find that. I love SO, I learn stuff even when I'm not trying to.

Comment: seems easiest just to have three overloaded functions that call a template function that doesnt check the types.  But the template function isnt declared in a header, so it's impossible to misuse.

Comment: @ildjarn:  Are int and signed int distinct types too?

Comment: @LeonidVolnitsky No. There is exactly the same question I came across on stackoverflow recently...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a type trait like that, you will have to make one yourself:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_char
{
    static const bool value = std::is_same<T, char>::value ||
            std::is_same<T, signed char>::value ||
            std::is_same<T, unsigned char>::value;
};

template <typename T>
void f(T t, typename std::enable_if<is_char<T>::value>::type* = 0)
{
}
```

Comment: This is disappointing since I think string literal should be trait important and implemented in type_traits by default.

Comment: @Yang : String literals are not limited to `char` variants -- there are also `char16_t`, `char32_t`, and `wchar_t` and their variants.

Comment: @ildjarn better off all except wide ones. Actually I'm considering all types abstracted from a single byte. There is no trait for byte either so I asked about char...:-)

Comment: @Yang: It sounds like you want to check `sizeof(T) == 1` to see if the type has a size of 1 byte.

Comment: @Jesse: other types can also have a size of 1 byte.

Comment: Hmm...I don't know but I always find myself reluctant to sizeof. But you are right and I guess I need some code refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

Well Jesse already provided a solution, but I'll leave mine here anyway.

```
// Tests whether the first template argument is equal to at least
// one of the rest of them
// e.g. any_is_same<int, char, bool, int>::value == true
// e.g. any_is_same<int, char, bool, std::string>::value == false

template<typename...>
struct any_is_same;

// Base cases

template<typename T, typename... Types>
struct any_is_same<T, T, Types...> {
    enum { value = true };
};

template<typename T>
struct any_is_same<T> {
    enum { value = false };
};

// Recursive

template<typename T, typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct any_is_same<T, Head, Tail...> {
    enum { value = any_is_same<T, Tail...>::value };
};

// Helper
template<typename T>
struct is_some_char {
    enum { value = any_is_same<T, char, signed char, unsigned char>::value };
};

template <typename type, typename std::enable_if<is_some_char<type>::value, int>::type = 0>
void foo(type x)
{

}
```

You can reuse the `any_is_same` type trait if you pretend to do the same for other types(like `int`/`unsigned int`/`signed int`/...):

```
template<typename T>
struct is_some_int {
    enum { value = any_is_same<T, int, signed int, unsigned int>::value };
};
```

Demo [here](http://ideone.com/KVFl5).

Comment: Hmm...it couldn't happen that you have copy-pasted it from your student project have you :-)? Nice codes...and there is [Head|Tail] even.

Comment: @Yang no, I haven't, why do you ask? Where is there a similar piece of code somewhere else?

Comment: Yes. "head, tail..." just reminds me of list comprehension in functional programming course I attend in school.

Comment: @Yang Yeah, well, it's a very common way of expressing list comprehensions/variadic templates in this case ;)